# Webkit not rendering custom scrollbars after making the element visible

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I have a page that has custom webkit scrollbars. Inline styling on the body has visibility:hidden on it and it's set to visible in the JavaScript, however the scrollbars aren't drawn unless you mess around with the size of the window (or the preview frame in the pen I link at the end).
I've tried this with Chrome 29 on Windows, and Safari 6.0.5 on Mac.

How can I fix this?

[Here's an example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKhCb)

If you open this up in a new tab make sure you refresh it so the tab is active while it's rendering, otherwise the scrollbars will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this i think this will help you.........

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 12px; height: 12px; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-button { background-color: #666; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track { background-color: #999; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece { background-color: #ffffff; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { height: 50px; background-color: #4CC417; border-radius: 3px; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner { background-color: #999; }

::-webkit-resizer { background-color: #666; }
```

Comment: Nope, still having the same issue.

Comment: try like this take div with 100% height and width and then put table in that

Comment: #tab {
  position: absolute;
 left: 0%;
 top: 0%;
  height:100%;
 width:100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

Comment: @sheodox what about this [link](http://codepen.io/Wizard/pen/Dsoim) it is working check it